# Why is EF Core SQLite returning incorrect int value?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

**Context**

I have an application writing to a SQLite database that has created duplicate records. I am creating a command prompt tool that reads in the database and outputs the data related to the duplicated records.

I connect to the SQLite database with EF Core, when I query the table for all records, the `itemID` property of every row is 1. When I open the database in [external tools](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) the values show up as expected with an an incremental ID.

IEnumerable visualizer of the actual result:

[image: IEnumerable visualizer of actual result showing all 1s]

Expected result as shown in data source using external tool

[image]

**Technology**

- .NET 8.0.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Reading a .db3 that was created using SQLite-NET-PCL 1.8.116
- Visual Studio 2022 - 17.9.1

```
CREATE TABLE "DefectReportAnswer" 
(
    "Report_id" varchar,
    "Item_id" integer,
    "Note" varchar,
    "Start_date" bigint,
    "End_date" bigint,
    "Defective" integer 
)
```

Code - model class:

```
public class DefectReportAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public string Report_id { get; set; }

    public int Item_id { get; set; }
    public string? Note { get; set; }

    public System.DateTimeOffset Start_date { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset End_date { get; set; }

    public bool Defective { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
internal class SQLiteDefectReportContext : DbContext
{
    public SQLiteDefectReportContext(string dbPath)
    {
        DbPath = dbPath;
    }

    public DbSet<DefectReportAnswer> DefectReportAnswer { get; set; }

    public string DbPath { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DefectReportAnswer>()
            .Property(d => d.Start_date)
            .HasConversion(
                d => d.Ticks,
                dt => new DateTimeOffset(
                        new DateTime(dt, DateTimeKind.Local).IsDaylightSavingTime() ? dt - TimeSpan.TicksPerHour : dt,
                        new TimeSpan(0)
                        )
            );

        modelBuilder.Entity<DefectReportAnswer>()
            .Property(d => d.End_date)
            .HasConversion(
                d => d.Ticks,
                dt => new DateTimeOffset(
                        new DateTime(dt, DateTimeKind.Local).IsDaylightSavingTime() ? dt - TimeSpan.TicksPerHour : dt,
                        new TimeSpan(0)
                        )
            );
    }
}
```

Main

```
private SQLiteDefectReportContext? _sqlite { get; set; }

var constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"];
_sql = new SQLDefectReportContext(constringVal);

var answers = _sqlite.DefectReportAnswer
    .Where(d => d.Report_id == reportID)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: "IEnumerable visualizer" does not look like a standard debugging visualizer to me. What is it? Looks broken to me in a way that it does not actually iterate.

Comment: are you sure this isn't just an ordering thing? since `Report_id` seems to be the key, have you tried ordering by that in both quesies?

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't show all the rows for readability, there are 104 returned relating to that report_id all of which have an item_id of 1.

Comment: @Ralf The IEnumerable Visualizer is the window that opens when clicking "view" on the answers var in debug. It looks like the standard visualiser I have always seen when inspecting collections this way. Please let me know if there is a more appropriate tool to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the unintended behaviour was created by an incorrect primary key attribute in the model code. This caused entity framework to see the non distinct "key" values and created the output.

Comment: While this was not a technical problem, I opted for leaving the question up for others who may have lazily created the same issue as me by poorly modeling their database. If anyone can further improve this answer to give more detail about why specifically it broke the itemID column please do so.